# Bash & cURL: Retrieve JSON from web API and search it for specific key:value pairs

Tags: json, bash, for-loop

I'm cURLing a web API for an application/json response, that response is a set of key value pairs, like this:

```
{"id":89,"name":"User saved 2018-07-03 12:01:47.337483","create_time":1530644507337,"auto":false,"recovered":false}
{"id":49,"name":"User saved 2018-05-24 12:33:53.927798","create_time":1527190433927,"auto":false,"recovered":false}
{"id":199,"name":"Daily backup 2018-10-22 02:37:37.332271","create_time":1540201057332,"auto":true,"recovered":false}
```

etc, etc...

I'd like to iterate through this response and find the highest value integer for the "id" key then save that as a variable.  If the above was my whole JSON I'd want to end up with variable=199.

Doing something like this:

```
MY_VARIABLE=$(curl -k -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: MyAPITarget apikey=${MY_APIKEY}" \
"https://targetserver/api/methodImCalling" |
```

The output of that is the JSON above.  Can I pipe that output into an array and iterate through it but only look for the value of "id" then do something similar to a:

```
for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
```

I've only been working with code a short while and most my background at this point is JS, trying to make the connection here for bash.  I'm trying to avoid using any "installed" tools whatsoever which is why I'm using bash, I'd like this script to run "out of the box" on any linux / unix platform.  Any tips?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a separate installation, but the tool you want is `jq`:

```
max_id=$(curl ... | jq -s 'map(.id) | max')
```

The standard tools that one can *expect* to be pre-installed simply aren't suitable for working with JSON.

While not standard, any machine that has `curl` installed is likely to have Python installed, and you can use its standard `json` module to process the JSON properly. Here's a somewhat ungainly one-liner:

```
curl ... | 
  python -c 'import json,sys; x="[%s]"%(",".join(sys.stdin),); print(max(y["id"] for y in json.loads(x)))'
```

Other non-standard but common languages (Perl, Ruby, etc) probably also have built-in ways to consume JSON.